# Android show textview graph

Tags: android, html, css

I am retrieving some html source code from a web page. When I use `Html.showHtml(htmlSource);`
it doesn't show the graph correctly.
Here is what the graph looks like on the web, without coloring:

```
Day  Date    Time    Event                          Location
Fri Sep 27  4:00 PM  Practice                   MSC Yellow
Sun Sep 29  3:00 PM MJBL Game vs Runnin Rebels  MSC Yellow
```

Here is the html and css for the graph:

```
    <table class="gymschedule">
    <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col />
        <col />
        <col />
        <col width="10" /> <!-- small! -->
        <col />
        <col />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>

                    <tr>
            <td>
                <nobr>Fri</nobr>
            </td>
            <td>
                <nobr>Nov 1</nobr>
            </td>
            <td>
                <nobr>4:00 PM</nobr>
            </td>
            <td>
                Practice                </td>
            <td>
                <nobr>MSC Yellow</nobr>
            </td>
        </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td>
                <nobr>Fri</nobr>
            </td>
            <td>
                <nobr>Nov 8</nobr>
            </td>
            <td>
                <nobr>4:00 PM</nobr>
            </td>
            <td>
                Practice                </td>
            <td>
                <nobr>MSC Yellow</nobr>
            </td>
        </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I display this graph in a text or image view correctly on an android phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android TextView does not support the `<table>` tag and its associated tags. See [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) for a list of HTML tags that are supported by TextView.

To display this you need to use a WebView. First, add the WebView to your layout:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then load the table HTML in the associated Activity:

```
String html = "<table> ..... </table>";

WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```